# How to Save default "Blender File View" window layout?

Tags: customization

The window that pops up when you Save As, Export, etc. I would like to re-arrange the left sidebar so that my Bookmarks are always on top, but I don't see a way to save this preference. Any help?

Comment: +1 Hmmm... interesting question, I would like to know that too. Since it not even saves the arrangement until the next time the window opens, it doesn't seem like this is customisable. The only thing I did and found useful is, in the _Preferences_ under _Save & Load_ > _File Browser_ you can disable _Show Locations_ "Recent" and "System". I'm usually never using "System" so I disabled it.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did too, and as far as I got. But the "bookmarks" and "recent" are far more valuable to me. I hate having to scroll down under "Volumes" all the time (or collapse it).

Comment: Well, to not have to scroll I simply made the window larger and without System, all is visible that I need. But interested in a way to save the layout I'm anyway.

Comment: This used to be saved in as preferences, prior to 2.8 refactor these settings were stored in the startup.blend, I think. After the changes introduced to accommodate  new workspaces and temporary windows we lost the ability to customize temporary window layouts like the file manager

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you for that clarification. Hopefully this is something they look to re-introduce, as it is probably one of the main windows everyone uses constantly.